# apache not translating localhost correctly

Tags: python, html, apache, debian, cgi

I have two files:
/var/www/index.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"http-equiv="content-type">
    <title>Hello</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    http://localhost/cgi-bin/hello.py
  </body>
</html>
```

and /usr/lib/cgi-bin/hello.py:

```
print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print '<html>'
print '<head>'
print '<title>Hello Word</title>'
print '</head>'
print '<body>'
print '<h2>Hello Word! This is my first CGI program</h2>'
data_uri = open('smiley.gif', 'rb').read().encode('base64').replace('\n', ''
)
img_tag = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,%s">' % data_uri    
print(img_tag)
print '</body>'
print '</html>'

#print ("hello world")
```

I can access hello.py correctly from a browser on another machine like this:

```
http://192.168.1.102/cgi-bin/hello.py
```

And it comes out as I would expect.
When I access the root index.html like this

```
http://192.168.1.102
```

I get this in my browser:

```
http://localhost/cgi-bin/hello.py
```

Here is my apache.conf file:

```
    # This is the main Apache server configuration file.  It contains the
    # configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
    # See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ for detailed information about
    # the directives and /usr/share/doc/apache2-common/README.Debian.gz about
    # Debian specific hints.
    #
    #
    # Summary of how the Apache 2 configuration works in Debian:
    # The Apache 2 web server configuration in Debian is quite different to
    # upstream's suggested way to configure the web server. This is because Debian's
    # default Apache2 installation attempts to make adding and removing modules,
    # virtual hosts, and extra configuration directives as flexible as possible, in
    # order to make automating the changes and administering the server as easy as
    # possible.

    # It is split into several files forming the configuration hierarchy outlined
    # below, all located in the /etc/apache2/ directory:
    #
    #       /etc/apache2/
    #       |-- apache2.conf
    #       |       `--  ports.conf
    #       |-- mods-enabled
    #       |       |-- *.load
    #       |       `-- *.conf
    #       |-- conf.d
    #       |       `-- *
    #       `-- sites-enabled
    #               `-- *
    #
    #
    # * apache2.conf is the main configuration file (this file). It puts the pieces
    #   together by including all remaining configuration files when starting up the
    #   web server.
    #
    #   In order to avoid conflicts with backup files, the Include directive is
    #   adapted to ignore files that:
    #   - do not begin with a letter or number
    #   - contain a character that is neither letter nor number nor _-:.
    #   - contain .dpkg
    #
    #   Yet we strongly suggest that all configuration files either end with a
    #   .conf or .load suffix in the file name. The next Debian release will
    #   ignore files not ending with .conf (or .load for mods-enabled).
    #
    # * ports.conf is always included from the main configuration file. It is
    #   supposed to determine listening ports for incoming connections, and which
    #   of these ports are used for name based virtual hosts.
    #
    # * Configuration files in the mods-enabled/ and sites-enabled/ directories
    #   contain particular configuration snippets which manage modules or virtual
    #   host configurations, respectively.
    #
    #   They are activated by symlinking available configuration files from their
    #   respective *-available/ counterparts. These should be managed by using our
    #   helpers a2enmod/a2dismod, a2ensite/a2dissite. See
    #   their respective man pages for detailed information.
    #
    # * Configuration files in the conf.d directory are either provided by other
    #   packages or may be added by the local administrator. Local additions
    #   should start with local- or end with .local.conf to avoid name clashes. All
    #   files in conf.d are considered (excluding the exceptions noted above) by
    #   the Apache 2 web server.
    #
    # * The binary is called apache2. Due to the use of environment variables, in
    #   the default configuration, apache2 needs to be started/stopped with
    #   /etc/init.d/apache2 or apache2ctl. Calling /usr/bin/apache2 directly will not
    #   work with the default configuration.


    # Global configuration
    #

    #
    # ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
    # configuration, error, and log files are kept.
    #
    # NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
    # mounted filesystem then please read the LockFile documentation (available
    # at <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#lockfile>);
    # you will save yourself a lot of trouble.
    #
    # Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
    #
    #ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

    #
    # The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
    #
    LockFile ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}/accept.lock

    #
    # PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
    # identification number when it starts.
    # This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
    #
    PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

    #
    # Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
    #
    Timeout 300

    #
    # KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
    # one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
    #
    KeepAlive On

    #
    # MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
    # during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
    # We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
    #
    MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

    #
    # KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
    # same client on the same connection.
    #
    KeepAliveTimeout 5

    ##
    ## Server-Pool Size Regulation (MPM specific)
    ##

    # prefork MPM
    # StartServers: number of server processes to start
    # MinSpareServers: minimum number of server processes which are kept spare
    # MaxSpareServers: maximum number of server processes which are kept spare
    # MaxClients: maximum number of server processes allowed to start
    # MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
    <IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
        StartServers          5
        MinSpareServers       5
        MaxSpareServers      10
        MaxClients          150
        MaxRequestsPerChild   0
    </IfModule>

    # worker MPM
    # StartServers: initial number of server processes to start
    # MinSpareThreads: minimum number of worker threads which are kept spare
    # MaxSpareThreads: maximum number of worker threads which are kept spare
    # ThreadLimit: ThreadsPerChild can be changed to this maximum value during a
    #              graceful restart. ThreadLimit can only be changed by stopping
    #              and starting Apache.
    # ThreadsPerChild: constant number of worker threads in each server process
    # MaxClients: maximum number of simultaneous client connections
    # MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
    <IfModule mpm_worker_module>
        StartServers          2
        MinSpareThreads      25
        MaxSpareThreads      75
        ThreadLimit          64
        ThreadsPerChild      25
        MaxClients          150
        MaxRequestsPerChild   0
    </IfModule>

    # event MPM
    # StartServers: initial number of server processes to start
    # MinSpareThreads: minimum number of worker threads which are kept spare
    # MaxSpareThreads: maximum number of worker threads which are kept spare
    # ThreadsPerChild: constant number of worker threads in each server process
    # MaxClients: maximum number of simultaneous client connections
    # MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
    <IfModule mpm_event_module>
        StartServers          2
        MinSpareThreads      25
        MaxSpareThreads      75
        ThreadLimit          64
        ThreadsPerChild      25
        MaxClients          150
        MaxRequestsPerChild   0
    </IfModule>

    # These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
    User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
    Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

    #
    # AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
    # for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
    # directive.
    #

    AccessFileName .htaccess

    #
    # The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
    # viewed by Web clients.
    #
    <Files ~ "^\.ht">
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
        Satisfy all
    </Files>

    #
    # DefaultType is the default MIME type the server will use for a document
    # if it cannot otherwise determine one, such as from filename extensions.
    # If your server contains mostly text or HTML documents, "text/plain" is
    # a good value.  If most of your content is binary, such as applications
    # or images, you may want to use "application/octet-stream" instead to
    # keep browsers from trying to display binary files as though they are
    # text.
    #
    # It is also possible to omit any default MIME type and let the
    # client's browser guess an appropriate action instead. Typically the
    # browser will decide based on the file's extension then. In cases
    # where no good assumption can be made, letting the default MIME type
    # unset is suggested  instead of forcing the browser to accept
    # incorrect  metadata.
    #
    DefaultType None


    #
    # HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
    # e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
    # The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
    # had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
    # each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
    # nameserver.
    #
    HostnameLookups Off

    # ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
    # If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
    # container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
    # logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
    # container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
    #
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    #
    # LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    #
    LogLevel warn

    # Include module configuration:
    Include mods-enabled/*.load
    Include mods-enabled/*.conf

    # Include list of ports to listen on and which to use for name based vhosts
    Include ports.conf

    #
    # The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
    # a CustomLog directive (see below).
    # If you are behind a reverse proxy, you might want to change %h into %{X-Forwarded-For}i
    #
    LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
    LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
    LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

    # Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
    # see the comments above for details.

    # Include generic snippets of statements
    Include conf.d/

    # Include the virtual host configurations:
    Include sites-enabled    
  <Directory "/var/www">
#    Options None
    Options FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    DirectoryIndex index.py index.html
  </Directory>
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to redirect to your python script, try using a meta tag like below.

`<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://localhost/cgi-bin/hello.py">`

Your html is not really executing any actions, just displaying the text you have typed in the body.